# Java - How to read a text file with Int's and Strings in the same line

Tags: java

If a text file contains

```
1 Apple
2 Banana
3 Orange
4 Carrot
5 Lemon
6 Lime
7 Mango
```

How can the file be read to store the contents of for example, line 4 carrot into a variable and line 6 Lime into a separate variable?

```
    //Get data from file
    String fruit = "";
    String greenFruit = "";


    FileReader file = new FileReader("my/file/path.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    System.out.println(fruit);
    System.out.println(greenFruit);
```

For the end result to be something like

```
"Fruit number 5 is a Lemon and Fruit Number 6 is a Lime"
```

Comment: You could read each line as a string and split the string by a space to separate the number and the fruit. From there it is just a case of casting the number to an integer etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String line = "";
String[] tokens;
int number;
String name;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    tokens = line.split(" ");

    // Use the following if you would rather split on whitespace for tab separated data
    // tokens = line.split("\\s+");

    number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    name = tokens[1];

    System.out.println("Fruit number " + number + " is a " + name + "."
}
```

Read up on the [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had not even heard of String.split(). Accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

We can make use java NIO api to read all lines from the file,

```
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

public static void main(final String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    final String output =
        Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(FileParser.class.getClassLoader().getResource("input.txt").toURI()))
            .stream()
            .map(SPACE::split)
            .map(it -> new Fruit(it[0], it[1]))
            .map(Fruit::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));

    System.out.println(output);
   }
}

class Fruit {
 private final String number;
 private final String name;

Fruit(final String number, final String name) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Fruit number ".concat(String.valueOf(number)).concat(" is a ").concat(name);
}
}
```

Output will be like below,

```
Fruit number 1 is a Apple and Fruit number 2 is a Banana and Fruit number 3 is a Orange and Fruit number 4 is a Carrot and Fruit number 5 is a Lemon and Fruit number 6 is a Lime and Fruit number 7 is a Mango
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read using `Scanner` and check if there is more using `hasNext()`

```
        FileReader file = new FileReader("file");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            int number = scanner.nextInt();
            String name = scanner.next();
        }
        scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 style:

```java
// normal solution
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        stream.foreach(line -> {
           tokens = line.split(" ");

           number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
           name = tokens[1];
           System.out.println("Fruit number " + number + " is a " + name + "."
        });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


// more OOP style
public class Fruit {
  private int number;
  private String name;

  public Fruit(String line) {
     String[] line = line.split(" ");
     this.number = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
     this.name = line[1];
  }  
}
List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            //1. convert all content to a object
            //2. convert it into a List
            list = stream
                    .map(Fruit::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

// then you can loop the list get what you want
```